# Python subprocess returned -11

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm making a test case, and whenever I call subprocess, I get the following error.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'TestRunner/TestRunner.py', '-r', '1000000']' returned non-zero exit status -11
```

The thing is, how I'm suppose to extract the actual error message?

I do not get anything from exit status -11.

Are there any temp file which stores the error details?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630389/python-error-codes

Comment: Did you mean exit status -1?

Comment: Its exit status -11 not -1

Comment: The error details (if any) are specific to the process that was run. If the process produced `stderr` output, you can look at that (if you're running without a terminal, you can open a file and pass `stdout=fileobj` and/or `stderr=fileobj` to send the output the process produced to a file to check (or use `Popen` instead of `check_call` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and you can call `.communicate()` on the `Popen` object to read it into your Python process). Aside from that, process exit codes are not standardized; it's up to the program run what each code means.

Comment: By looking for Glothlin's link, looks like it's segmentation failure, weird.

Comment: Or ignore me and look at what @McGlothlin linked; forgot about the "negative status means killed by signal" rule.

Comment: install [`faulthandler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/), to get the Python traceback on crash.

Comment: Looks like this problem is specific to Linux....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

Based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630389/python-error-codes) I provided, it looks like you're running into a segfault because a thread did something it wasn't supposed to. Perhaps it would be helpful to check out this link as well: https://wiki.python.org/moin/CrashingPython

You can also try the highest voted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035541/what-causes-a-python-segmentation-fault) question. I have little experience debugging segfaults in Python specifically, but that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: I'll take your answer for now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command manually:

```
/usr/bin/python TestRunner/TestRunner.py -r 1000000
```

If the -11 return is interpreted as "exited with signal 11 (Seg fault)", the shell should print a message saying such.