# What exactly is the SIGABRT error?- Codechef

Tags: c++, sigabrt

//The problem is not on my computer, the problem is "SIGABRT Run time error" When I post it //on the codechef page. Please help.
//No details are actually required as the required output is coming on my laptop. Its only //on codechef that the problem exists.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
```

//Alien Chefs question on codechef

```
using namespace std;

int check(int, int[], int[]);

int *grpDone = 0;
int n, q, k, s[100001], e[100001], alienTime[21];
```

// Please see where I should make changes as this is the 1st time i posted something on codechef.
    struct timeDetail
    {
        int count;
        int curr;
        int *vids;

```
    timeDetail() {
        count = 0;
        curr = 0;
        vids = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }

    ~timeDetail() {
        free(vids);
    }

    void addVid(int n) {
        vids[curr++] = n;
    }

    int getNumVids() {
        return curr;
    }
}*atTime ;
int main() {
    int maxTime = 0;
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        scanf(" %d %d", &s[i], &e[i]);
        if(e[i] > maxTime)
            maxTime = e[i];
    }

    atTime = new timeDetail[maxTime+1];
    scanf(" %d", &q);
    for(int i=1; i<=q; i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &k);

        ::grpDone = (int*)calloc(n+1, sizeof(int));
        int totVids = 0;
        for(int j=1;j<=k;j++) {
            scanf(" %d", &alienTime[j]);
            int numVids = 0;
            numVids = check(alienTime[j], s, e);
            totVids += numVids;
        }
        printf("%d\n", totVids);
        free(::grpDone);
    }
    return 0;
}

int check(int t, int s[], int e[]) {
    int prevFound = atTime[t].getNumVids();
    int numVids = 0;
    if(prevFound > 0) {
        for(int i = 1; i<=prevFound; i++) {
            if(::grpDone[atTime[t].vids[i]] == 1)
                continue;
            else {
                ::grpDone[atTime[t].vids[i]] = 1;
                numVids++;
            }
        }
        return numVids;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if(t>=s[i] && t<=e[i]) {
            atTime[t].addVid(i);
            if(::grpDone[i] == 1) {
                continue;
            } else {
                ::grpDone[i] = 1;
                numVids++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numVids;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does a process get SIGABRT (signal 6)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6)

Comment: // be sure to check the comments.
// ;-)