# issue reg. SIGABRT with input file in FEAPpv

Tags: fortran

I am running a program to compute the thermo-electro-elastic response of a solid material under certain conditions. Every time I specify the input file after executing the feappv command, I receive the following error message.

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.
Backtrace for this error:
Aborted (core dumped)

I dont understand the meaning of this error. Please help.

Thank u all

Comment: This can mean anything. Enable all debugging and error checking options, post your code and FULL error message you got. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6

Comment: If your problem is what caused the abort from FEAPpv, you will likely get more support from [their user forums](http://feap.berkeley.edu/forum/index.php) .

Answer (score 1):

Your program received the `SIGABRT` signal.  This generally  happens through invocation of the `abort()` function from C or by executing `call abort` from Fortran. See the documentation of your compiler for details. It is common programming practice to call abort when some severe error in the program or inconsistency in input data has been detected.