# Catching libc error messages, redirecting from /dev/tty

Tags: c++, c, libc

I am trying to catch error messages that libc generates when it detects error conditions.  For example, my test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char* p = (char*)malloc(10);
   free(p);
   free(p);
}
```

Generates this output

```
$ ./main
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000124b010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d1fd)[0x7f8c121291fd]
./main[0x400b86]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f8c120cdaf5]
./main[0x400a79]
... <snip>
```

However, it is not being written to stderr or stdout, but /dev/tty (which I discovered using strace)

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
writev(3, [{"*** Error in `", 14}, {"./main", 6}, {"': ", 3}, {"double free or corruption (fastt"..., 35}, {": 0x", 4}, {"00000000011bf010", 16}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000011bf010 ***
) = 83
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0f2f7ac000
write(3, "======= Backtrace: =========\n", 29======= Backtrace: =========
) = 29
writev(3, [{"/lib64/libc.so.6", 16}, {"(", 1}, {"+0x", 3}, {"7d1fd", 5}, {")", 1}, {"[0x", 3}, {"7f0f2ea2a1fd", 12}, {"]\n", 2}], 8/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d1fd)[0x7f0f2ea2a1fd]
) = 43
writev(3, [{"./main", 6}, {"[0x", 3}, {"400b86", 6}, {"]\n", 2}], 4./main[0x400b86]
) = 17
writev(3, [{"/lib64/libc.so.6", 16}, {"(", 1}, {"__libc_start_main", 17}, {"+0x", 3}, {"f5", 2}, {")", 1}, {"[0x", 3}, {"7f0f2e9ceaf5", 12}, {"]\n", 2}], 9/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f0f2e9ceaf5]
) = 57
writev(3, [{"./main", 6}, {"[0x", 3}, {"400a79", 6}, {"]\n", 2}], 4./main[0x400a79]
) = 17
```

How do I redirect this to a file? The standard stdout and stderr redirects don't work.   I need to catch this for a systemd service, and right now, the output is disappearing into the ether.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an UNDOCUMENTED (not in the glibc documentation!) answer by inspecting the [libc source code, libc_fatal.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c;h=2d99c46cf8e2ccfc2c09847d864b45b0d95efb91;hb=HEAD).

Set the following environment variable to anything

```
LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1
```

to cause libc to write to `stderr` instead of `/dev/tty`.