# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I get this error when using the library.
I read about it and it says that it is a Native level error .
But really didn't get any way to fix it, so any info would be helpful.

```
10-08 09:03:37.596 9586-10028/com.example.marti.tv E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648 
10-08 09:03:37.599 9586-10028/com.example.marti.tv I/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] prepareForAdaptivePlayback(1280x720) 
10-08 09:03:37.600 9586-10028/com.example.marti.tv I/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] DRC Mode: Adaptive Mode 
10-08 09:03:37.600 9586-10028/com.example.marti.tv A/: frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/foundation/ABitReader.cpp:50 CHECK_LE( n,32u) failed: 40 vs. 32 
10-08 09:03:37.601 9586-10028/com.example.marti.tv A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10028 (CodecLooper)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does a process get SIGABRT (signal 6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6)

Comment: not really, I thought it would be different for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a bug in the library, or, more probably, you provide some wrong parameters to your call. Or worse, there is some memory corruption from previous operations, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413215/952135.