# How to simulate a crash in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Very simple question but I can't find any solution on the net.

**Is it possible to force a Qt app to crash?**

This is only for development purposes as I'd like to experiment with the crash report.

Comment: Create a pointer ```QPushButton *button``` but no instance of it. Try to call a method of ```button``` and it will crash (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: The dereference of a null pointer will crash on pretty much any platform Qt runs on, with exception of some big iron (mainframes), unless the compiler optimizes it out (according to the standard, it can!).

Comment: On Windows you can write a DLL that crashes, then inject it into your process with MS Detours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember, we're on **StackOverflow** :-)

How about:

```
int foo(int p) {
    return foo(p)+foo(p);
}

foo(0);
```

PS for something tamer and more Qt-specific, you can experiment with qFatal:

```
qFatal("boom");
```

Comment: LOL, even if it work'ed 100% of the time, he probably can't use it for the purpose of a crash report. You have my up-vote for the creativity though :)

Comment: @user1708860 didn't try, but I'd say it would give a proper crash report.

Comment: signal 6 is thrown when an internal error occurs such as stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6 . Which means that any allocation from this point on, including stack allocations, may not work. That makes it alot harder to make a crash report... (I can't find any other resources on this matter, so i could be horribly wrong here, it's based mostly on what wer'e doing with our signal handlers)

Comment: @user1708860 I've tested on my machine, I get SIGSEGV (segfault). Strange ...?

Comment: I this that this is undefined behavior, we could both be right, and we could both be wrong.

Comment: On my machine, the app crashes without crash report (Mac OSX)

Comment: I'd say not UB but implementation dependant. We're just asking for infinite resources, aren't we ?

Comment: @VincentDuprez interesting. NB Windows here.

Comment: @VincentDuprez I also had to mention qFatal just in case, since you're asking specifically for Qt.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an exception and never catch it, this may or may not be what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

this is the cross-platform most robust solution i could find: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/raise

<strike>If you are using *nix systems, you can use the [raise](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html) call.</strike>

I assume you are already platform specific as you are making a crash report, which i know of no way to make cross platform at the moment. I don't know about a similar solution that would work in a windows environment, one probably exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a segfault using the signal Linux library:

```
#include <signal.h>

void raiseSegfault()
{
    int error = raise(SIGSEGV);
    if (error != 0) {
        std::cout << "cannot raise segfault" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will reliably raise a segmentation fault or exit and will not rely on undefined behaviour.