# When does SIGABRT runtime error arise and how to debug in such cases?

Tags: c++, stl, runtime-error

I have been trying to submit solution to a question since yesterday but still in vain. I am getting a run-time error for larger testcases. On researching about this runtime error I came to know that it is caused by using excessive memory. I have an array of size `<=10^6` and a vector of `<=10^12` integer pairs. Should this cause stack overflow, especially in the case of the vector?
PS: I have used C++ STL  many times but never faced memory overflow in these limits.

Comment: *"vector of <=10^12 integer pairs"* That's up to 8TB of memory. You'll need to improve your algorithm. (Or rent some computer that has that kind of RAM, but that's most likely not the point of the exercise. ;) )

Comment: 10^12 integers are 4000GB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does a process get SIGABRT (signal 6)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6)

Comment: @BaummitAugen.....thank you....I completely forgot that 10^12 is square of 10^6 not twice :P

Comment: @WernerHenze....I mentioned in the question about `reserach on such error`....actually meant the question u mentioned ...................:)

Comment: SIGABRT got nothing to do with c++ or STL, it's platform dependent  (POSIX) way to handle catastrophic failure. you're not only out of stack, you most likely out of addressable area of memory at all. a) you should compartmentalize if you actually need this large amount of data, you cant process t at once, unless you have some supercomputer b) very large data structures never should be storage with  automatic life span

Comment: @Leandros  10^12 _pairs_ of integers, it's 8TB on  system with 32bit int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're running out of memory (unless your system has **>8TB** of virtual memory) and `std::bad_alloc` is thrown. An unhandled exception will cause a call to `terminate()` which will call `abort()`.

If you really want to debug this, run your program under `gdb`, you should see something like:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```

Then you can type `bt` to see the stack trace.