# Prevent glibc from showing extra abort information

Tags: c, linux, memory, signals, abort

Unix signal 6, `SIGABRT`, is thrown when `abort()` is called in the program, or when a process attempts to (de)allocate invalid memory<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3413166/6850771)</sup>. If I were to simply put `abort()` in a program like so:

```
int main(void)
{
    abort();
}
```

My system would print `Aborted`. But, if I were to actually attempt to deallocate invalid memory:

```
int main(void)
{
    free(main);
}
```

My system prints:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400536 ***
Aborted
```

Some systems give an entire stack trace.<sup>[[2]](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT6MsPzNFk6uaSwEI0opSUzVAoprWXLX//wMA)</sup>

I want to turn off this extra information, so that when I attempt to mess with invalid memory, all I see is `Aborted`. How can I do that?

Note that this is not a compiler-specific thing, as GCC, TCC, and Clang all show the same thing.

Comment: Even more important... How do you stop the error reporting, like Apport, Windows Error Reporting, Apple Crash Report, etc. They take all the sensitive information in your app, like passwords and private keys, and ship them off to a third party.

Comment: If you don't want to get reports for undefined behaviour, how about just writing correct code? That way there is no output at all.

Comment: Redirect stderr

Comment: @Olaf - The reports can be generated for more than undefined behavior. An `assert` without `NDEBUG` defined will generate a `SIGABRT` because Posix specifies `assert` calls `abort()`, which raises `SIGABRT`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, I do not want to catch it and implement my own ... thingy, I just want glibc to not display the extra information.

Comment: @Olaf - *"constraint is not met (which would result in an illegal proram state -> UB in the final consequence)"* - Wrong. Undefined Behavior has a very specific meaning in C, C++ and Objective C. A program operating outside its parameters is not necessarily UB. Its just a buggy program.

Comment: @Olaf - [Apple Technical Q&A QA1561](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html): *"How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?"* The answer is *"If during development or testing it is necessary to terminate your application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended"*. Also see [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980740/608639) No Undefined Behavior required.

Comment: @jww: I will not further discuss this. It has been unrelated to the question and my comment from the beginning. You put words in my mouth and I made the mistake to bite. Therefore I deleted my other comments. Please remember comments are not for discussion. (Finally: Please provide the ISO/IEC number of that Apple document. Vendor-specific documents are hardly authoritative)

Comment: @Olaf - I thought so, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate of the question to intercept aborts.  These outputs are produced *before* `abort()` is called.  Whilst it's still a good idea to write code that exits cleanly, I disagree that the answers to that question would be any use for this - voting to reopen.