# Sigabrt error in c programing

Tags: c, arrays, printf, sigabrt

plz help me to remove SIBABRT error for the following code,plz suggest me why this error occurs even after getting correct output

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char x[25],y[25];
int i,j=0;
scanf("%s",x);
for(i=0;i<strlen(x);i++)
{
    if(x[i]>=97 && x[i]<=122)
    {
        y[j]=x[i]-32;
        j++;
    }
    else if(x[i]>=65 && x[i]<=90)
    {
        y[j]=x[i]+32;
        j++;
    }

}
printf("%s",y);}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",x);` --> `scanf("%24s",x);`

Comment: What is `97`?  What is `122`?  Why  are you adding `32`?

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output?

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging this?  I'd expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB.  Please [edit] your question to summarize what the debugging tools told you and why they didn't solve your problem.  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You might be interested in `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()` and `tolower()`.

Comment: Don't say `97` when you can say `'a'`. The latter is portable and readable. The former is neither.

Comment: Hint: avoid "magic" numbers such as 97, 122, 65, 90, 32 etc. Use `'a'`, `'z'`, `'A'`, `'Z'` , `'a' - 'A'` etc.

Comment: As a side note, read this [when does process get SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6)

Answer (score 1):

Think of the difference between the source and the destination array, something is missing in the destination. The null-terminator.

*Note: Both the arrays are local variable with automatic storage and unless initialized explicitly, their content is indeterminate.*

Without a null-terminator in place, `printf()` will go out of bound for the supplied array while printing with `%s` which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The easiest way to handle this is zero-initilize the arrays, like

```
  char x[25] = {0} ,y[25] = {0};
```

which makes all the elements of the arrays set to 0, and the same value being used as null-terminator, you are not required to add one manually to the destination array.

Also, FWIW,

- You should length-limit the input to prevent buffer overflow from longer than expected input, using something along the line `scanf("%24s",x);`
- better to use `fgets()` to take the user input. If, iff, you have to use `scanf()`,you can use it but please use proper error checking.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is less than 25 characters, then the string will be null terminated. If the size exceeds the array size specified then it overwrites the memory not belonging to the array.

So `fgets()` is the alternative for `scanf()` in such case.