# My Logger deamon service receives SIGABRT signal, what scenarios in which program could terminate due to this?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

My c++ scribe client application(multi threaded- Thrift framework) sends periodically logs to 
central server, but it crash after some time, After research i found problem with signals, 
So i have used code to handle signals, after that i found it receives SIGABRT signal, 
i don't know how to solv this,

```
class MyTimer : public CppTimer{
void timerEvent() {

    cout<<"timer Event"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < g_config->logFileNames.size(); i++) {
        try{    

            int ret = -1;
            string tempfile = g_config->tempFolder + g_config->logFileNames[i];
            string category = g_config->logCategories[g_config->logFileNames[i]];
            //addLog("timerEvent: reading file ...");
            string content = read_file_content(tempfile);

            trim(content);
            if(content.size() == 0)
                continue;

            try{
                g_client->reinitialize();
            }catch(TException &tx){
                stringstream ss1;
                ss1<<"cause :"<<tx.what()<<endl;
                addLog(ss1.str().c_str());
                g_transport->close();
                g_transport->open();
                addLog("Connection reinitialized");
            }catch(std::exception& e){
                stringstream ss;
                ss<<"std :: exception in timerEvent! : in std catch : "<<e.what();
                addLog(ss.str());
                //g_client->reinitialize();
                g_transport->close();
                g_transport->open();
                addLog("connection Established");
            }
            addLog("timerEvent: reading file success.");
            stringstream ss, srs;
            ss <<"> "<<tempfile;
            system(ss.str().c_str());
            addLog("timerEvent: appending file name ");
            LogEntry le;
            le.message = content;
            le.category = category;
            addLog("timerEvent: pushing in queue ");
            std::vector<LogEntry> messages;
            messages.push_back(le);
            // write to scribe server
            addLog("timerEvent: queue ready ");
            try{
                ret = g_client->Log(messages);
            }catch(TException &tx){
                stringstream ss;
                ss<<"TimerEvent :"<<tx.what()<<endl;
                addLog("1 Server Connection Failed");
                addLog(ss.str());
                g_transport->close();
                g_transport->open();
                addLog("connection Established");
                ret = g_client->Log(messages);
                //printf("ERROR: %s\n",tx.what());
            }catch(std::exception& e){
                stringstream ss;
                ss<<"exception in timerEvent! send : in std catch : "<<e.what();
                addLog(ss.str());
                //g_client->reinitialize();
                g_transport->close();
                g_transport->open();
                addLog("connection Established");
                ret = g_client->Log(messages);
        }

            //g_client->reinitialize();
            addLog("timerEvent: data sent to server ");
            if(0 != ret){
                addLog("Log data was not sent to server:");
                cout<<"Log data was not sent to server:"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                addLog("Log data was sent to server:"); 
                cout<<"Log data was sent to server:"<<endl; 
            }
            stringstream sss;
            sss<<"Category : "<<category;
            addLog(sss.str());
            cout<<sss.str()<<endl;
            sss.str("");
            sss<<"Content : " <<content;
            //addLog(sss.str()); //prints logs contents
            cout<<sss.str()<<endl;
        }
        catch(boost::exception const& ex){
            stringstream ss;
            ss<<"boost :: exception in timerEvent! : in boost catch : "<<boost::diagnostic_information(ex);
            addLog(ss.str());
            g_transport->close();
            g_transport->open();
            addLog("connection Established");
            //throw 10;
        }
        catch(std::exception& e){
            stringstream ss;
            ss<<"std :: exception in timerEvent 269! : in std catch : "<<e.what();
            addLog(ss.str());
            //g_client->reinitialize();
            g_transport->close();
            g_transport->open();
            addLog("connection Established");
        }
        catch(...){
            addLog("exception in timerEvent! : in default catch ");
            g_transport->close();
            g_transport->open();
            addLog("connection Established");
        }
        //transport->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6

Comment: Unrelated, but you could simplify the loop (`for(int i = 0; i < g_config->logFileNames.size(); i++)`) by doing `for(const auto& logfile : g_config->logFileNames)`. You wouldn't have to lookup the name via the index multiple times after that. Do you know which line it is that causes `abort()` to be called? If not, add debug logging or examine the `core` dump that I assume have been produced.