# In Linux coredump found Perl segmentation faults

Tags: linux, perl, coredump

I am using a customized OS based on Oracle Linux 6.10. I have few customized command that helps to find information like firewall rules,hardware information but if I run those command then coredumps are generated.

There are 4 core files found on the one of my OracleLinux6.10 server like core.top.myrole.34089.bt

Below are the error that say it is generated by top.myrole 'Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted/No symbol table info available':

```
10/15/2019 13:54:57 core.top.myrole.34089.bt

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

top.myrole: No such file or directory.

Missing separate debuginfo for the main executable file

Try: yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install

/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/81/7805fb3de3731d5c36c8f7da38040ee6d510ea

[New Thread 34090]

[New Thread 34089]

Core was generated by \top.myrole'.`

Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.

#0 0x000000347960f00d in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 34089):

#0 0x000000347960f00d in ?? ()

No symbol table info available.

#1 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()

No symbol table info available.
```

After the above line 'No symbol table' error would now repeat for multiple threads.

Then found other coredump also generated while running a customized command 'hardwareshow'(this command is not linux command but it is customized within our distribution). The log shows that core was generated by '/usr/bin/perl /usr/product/bin/iprule show' :

```
10/14/2019 20:44:25, core.hardwareshow.8944.bt
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New Thread 55835]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by \/usr/bin/perl /usr/product/bin/iprule show--type=rule --protocol=ipv6 -'.Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.#0  0x0000003479a80829 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/libperl.so`

------------
10/14/2019 04:19:59, core.iprule.55835.bt
```

I checked the Perl version used in the machine and it seems it is Perl5 , (still needs to confirm if it`s 5.10).How do I address this issue, I heard from some Perl experts that Perl upgrade to a new version can help here still I would want to hear from multiple Linux developers/Perl Developers about this error.

Comment: Cross-post: http://redd.it/dlfg4j

Comment: As it stands, your question is "how do I debug a C program", which is far too large of a topic.

Comment: At the very least, you should get a stack backtrace!

Comment: You say you got a seg fault, but signal 6 is [SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6) on my system, not SIGSEGV

Answer (score 1):

The perl interpreter will coredump if: there is a bug in its implementation; if certain pathological Perl code patterns are used (e.g. infinite recursion calling tie or overload handlers); or if there is a bug in an external module that uses C-level code (like XS modules). Determining what the fault is can be hard. If you just want the problem to go away, then upgrading everything to a more recent version is probably the path of least resistance. Note that the perl 5.10.0 release is about 12 years old.