# Batch aborted in shell script

Tags: c, shell, batch-processing, abort

my pro*c program is run this way :

```
./SETC0570 >log.txt 2>&1
```

I got this line in log.txt

```
/path/to/shell_script/SEUX0570.sh: line 212: 41055: Abort
```

I know 212 in the line number where SETC0570  was called.
But what is 41055 ?

What could cause my pro*c program to terminate abruptly without leaving enough root cause traces ?

What to do to have these traces ..?

Comment: SIGABRT is, well, a _signal_. There's not enough information here to know what sent it or why.

Comment: I'd start by attaching a debugger to your C program.

Comment: See [When does a process get SIGABRT (signal 6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6). I'd argue that this isn't really a shell question at all; the shell is just reporting how the C program died, it had nothing to do with the C program exiting.

Comment: I guess that `41055` is PID number.

Comment: 41055 is indeed the PID.