# Nomad .net Core 8 service and Exit Code: 134, Signal: 6

Tags: hashicorp, rhel8, nomad

I am trying to setup very simple .net core 8 console app running under nomad.
Here is my job specification:

```
job "my-service" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "batch"

  group "group1" {
     scaling {
      min     = 1
      max     = 10
      enabled = true
}

constraint {
    attribute = "10.168.30.45"
    operator  = "set_contains"
    value     = "${attr.unique.network.ip-address}"
  }


   task "raw" {
      driver = "exec"

      artifact {
        source      = "https://my-registry.com/my-service.zip"
        destination = "local"
      }

      config {
        command = "/local/my-service/My.Linux.Service"
        args = ["arg1"]
      }
resources {
        memory = 64
      }
    }

    }
  }
```

My nomad client is RHEL 8. I installed .net 8 on my RHEL box and also run my service executing the command `My.Linux.Service arg1` and it works just fine as seen below:

[image]

When I run my nomad job, I get the following error:

> Exit Code: 134, Signal: 6

and job just terminates

I also enabled raw_exec plugin on my Nomad client and tried that as well with no avail.
Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6 . It's on you, _your program_ has failed and sent itself a signal. Debug your program..

Comment: @KamilCuk, Thanks for your response. I added an image that shows my service is running just fine on Nomad client `10.168.30.45` I have put restriction on my job specification.

Comment: Hi, well, logs doesn't mean anything to me, because it's _your application_, which I know nothing about it. `memory = 64` is pretty low. Bottom line, you have to debug your application why it receives SIGABRT. There are `strace` `valgrind`, sanitizers, `gdb`, debugging in Linux is a well known big topic.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I removed memory restrictions of 64mb and have still the same error. Since this is a .net core service (Long running service), should I be running it as `exec` or `row_exec`? I was also looking at `systemd-nspawn` but it seems, my RHEL8 box doesn't have that.

Comment: `should I` Try with `raw_exec` and see what happens. Possibility is that files are missing with `exec` driver. It is a problem with the application itself. Does the command run without nomad?

Comment: I think I found an issue. but I don't have any solution yet. Underlying error was "reference not set to an instance of an object". There is a possibility that it can't find my appsettings.json. I am downloading artifact in "local" and then my executable and appsettings are in "/local/my-service/". In my command, I am starting from "/local" so it seems, it is looking for an appsettings.json in /local directory instead. Is there a way I can `cd` into directory "/local/my-service" and then execute that command?

Comment: Sooo write a script, that does `cd`, and run it. Even `command = "sh" args = ["-c", "cd dir && ./app"]`

Comment: I tried `command = "sh" args = ["-c", "/local/my-service && ./my-service arg1"]` and I get the following error: "/usr/bin/sh: - : invalid option" I tried both `exec` and 'raw_exec'. I think I am getting closer. Thanks for all your help

Comment: `"/usr/bin/sh: - : invalid option"` that would be the error if you would execute `sh '- '`. Check for invisible characters, it should be `"-c"`.

Comment: Indeed it has one whitespace character. As soon as I removed that whitespace character, my service started working without any issues. Can you please post it as an answer? I can then accept it. Again, Thanks a lot. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported, the issue was that the executable was expecting to be run from the same working directory as other files from the archive.

The simplest solution is to change the current working directory before executing the executable with just a small shell script.

```
command = "sh"
args = ["-c", "cd ${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/my-service && ./my-service arg1"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue has been resolved and my service is working as expected